# What rules can I apply for divisible numbers?

Tags: project-euler

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler problem 12](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12). I've figured out a fast algorithm for the triangle numbers, but to see if they are devisable is just a pain...

```
## Code in Python ##

def checkdivisable_function(num):

    dev=    500 # Devisable By 501 numbers (as set in task)
    j=      0   # Counts by how many numbers it can be divided. 
    i=      0   # Running integer of the current divisor.

    while i<=num:
        i=i+1           
        if num%i==0:       # Success! A new divisor.
            j+=1                

        if j==dev:         # Success! Sufficient number of devisors.
            print "Solution:",num
            print "Finished!"
            exit()
    return False
```

In a nutshell:
It takes a triangle number, and for every number below that using the running integer `i` it tries to divide. If it is devisable `(num%i==0)` it will add that to the running integer `j`, that counts how many numbers it has been divisable by.

**This algorithm is by brute force and has turned out to be veeerryyy slow. I'm wondering if there's any rule or relationship for this which I can implement to speed it up; do divisible numbers have some property that I've missed?**

*Not asking to rewrite my code here, that's simply for reference, but asking what other properties I might use to quickly eliminate unintersting numbers :)*

Answer (score 1):

The $n$th triangular number is $1+2+ \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}2$. Now for a given triangluar number, take the square root of it and check around the square root to find what $n$ is. And since $\gcd(n,n+) = 1$, it suffices to check for the prime factors of $n$ and $n+1$ separately. Just keep in mind when $n \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, that you need to omit two from the list of prime factors.

Comment: You don't have to check around.  Given a triangular number $t$, you can solve the quadratic $2t=n^2+n$ to get $n$ directly.

Comment: I did not know how much time it takes to solve a quadratic versus checking maybe around $2\sqrt{n}$ numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The number of divisors function $\tau(n)$ is one of the basic functions from number theory. There is a simple recurrence for it:

- $\tau(p^n) = n+1$ for any prime $p$
- $\tau(mn) = \tau(m) \tau(n)$ whenever $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime

so if you find the factorization of a number $n$, you can compute $\tau(n)$ rather quickly.